# Split a csv by date column and save to a different folder

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I have a csv file like this.

budget.csv

```
id,date,budget
1,2019/11/01,100
1,2019/11/02,300
1,2019/11/03,200
2,2019/11/01,600
2,2019/11/02,500
2,2019/11/03,400
```

How can I split the CSV file by date and save it into different locations that haven't existed? The output structure I want is like this.

```
./2020/11/01/budget.csv
./2020/11/02/budget.csv
./2020/11/03/budget.csv
```

I tried something like `awk -F'[,]' '{print >> "./2020/11/01/'$2'.csv"}' budget.csv` but I need to fix for creating new folders and to split the date somehow. Any suggestions? I am running in on Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
while IFS="," read -r id date budget; do
    if ((nr++)); then                   # skip the header line
        mkdir -p "$date"                # mkdir recursively
        echo "$id,$date,$budget" >> "$date/budget.csv"
    fi
done < budget.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for handling multiple output files:

```
tail +2 budget.csv | cut -d, -f2 | sort -u | xargs mkdir -p
awk -F, 'NR>1{print > ($2 "/" FILENAME)} budget.csv
```

With other awks you'd have to close() the output files as you go.